# How to directly get the TeXForm of each steps from Rubi?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, latex, rubi

It's easy to read the steps from Rubi, but kind of tired to copy it out of as $\LaTeX$. That's what now I do:

```
Int[x Sin[x], x]//Steps
```

For example,click one step, then paste it to .nb, then //TeXForm to get the TeX code. (kind of monkey job)

[image]

I've tried FullForm, get nothing, `// Trace` gives back a lot of things, which seems a bit hard for me to pick out what I want. So I want a "automatical" way to do this.

Comment: Hi. I found small problem trying to add your function to my report. Since all integrals I use come from lists, and you have `SetAttributes[IntWithStepsOfTeXForm, {HoldFirst}];` then when I pass the integral to your function, it does not work. Here is an example. `lst = {{Log[1 + x], x}};
result = IntWithStepsOfTeXForm[ Int[lst[[1, 1]], lst[[1, 2]]]  ] ;` And now the result does not work.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ab5TV.png)

Comment: fyi, I posted separate question on this here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221547/problem-calling-function-defined-with-holdfirst  I could not find solution myself.

Comment: @Nasser  `IntWithStepsOfTeXForm[Int[#, x]] & /@ {Sin[x], Cos[x]/x^2, 
   Sin[x]/x^2} // MaTeX` can work.

Answer (score 7):

A better version is here:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221559/68689

---

I found this option:

```
RubiPrintInformation -> False
```

And then write this:

```
SetAttributes[IntWithStepsOfTeXForm, {HoldFirst}];
IntWithStepsOfTeXForm[j_] := 
 With[{TeX2Str = Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX},
  Steps[j, RubiPrintInformation -> False] //
         Flatten //
        Most //
       Select[Head@# =!= RubiRule &] //
      # /. RubiIntermediateResult[x_] -> x & //
     (*ToString@*TeXForm is OK*)
     Map["=&" <> (TeX2Str[HoldForm @@ #]) <> "\\\\" &] //
    # /. {a___} -> {
        "\\begin{aligned}",
        TeX2Str@HoldForm@j,
        a,
        "\\end{aligned}"} & // StringRiffle
  ]
```

This function returns a string.

**Usage:**

[image]

Or use [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) and then copy the result to clipboard for following use.

[image]